# Count in a VIEW

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Deaths table where each personID display that died. There is also a column for reason of death and a date for when he/she died.

I need to count all the people that died by Illness, Accident, Suicide, etc.

I want my output to be like this:

`| Illness | Accident | Suicide |
 |   32    |    55    |    3    |`

I can easily create a view like this:

`CREATE VIEW viewDeaths AS
 SELECT COUNT(personID) AS Illness
 WHERE Reason = 'Illness';`

And it will display it correct, but how do I do it with multiple conditions?

The main purpose is to display the different values for each reason on a graph in a C# application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use multiple subqueries:

```
CREATE VIEW viewDeaths AS
    SELECT Illness = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Deaths d
                      WHERE d.Reason = 'Illness'),
           Accident = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Deaths d
                      WHERE d.Reason = 'Accident'),
           Suicide = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Deaths d
                      WHERE d.Reason = 'Suicide')
```

Answer (score 0):

In this way:

```
 CREATE VIEW viewDeaths AS
     SELECT Reason, COUNT(personID) AS Illness
    -- WHERE Reason IN (.....)
     GROUP BY Reason
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a view, you can't use dynamic SQL, so either a static `PIVOT` or a `CASE` expression would be the best way to do it:

```
CREATE VIEW viewDeaths 
AS
SELECT  SUM(CASE WHEN Reason = 'Illness' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Illness,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Reason = 'Accident' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Accident,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Reason = 'Suicide' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Suicide 
FROM dbo.Deaths;
```

Comment: I wonder if this is more efficient than [my](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33501394/284240) three queries. **Edit** Tested it on one of my views, my 3-query approach returned the result immediately whereas the `SUM` approach needed 18 seconds. Interesting

Comment: [Here's](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/119945/why-is-count-faster-than-sum/119953#119953) the explanation why the `SUM` is slower. Use a `WHERE`.